# I brought this book with me to

Tags: pronouns, infinitives

a. I brought this book with me to read.

b. I brought this book with me to read **it**.

c. They took John to imprison.

d. They took John to imprison **him**.

Are the pronouns at the end of (b) and (d) necessary?

I think they should be there and without them the sentences don't work.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sentence a. is correct and natural

Sentence b. the pronoun is redundant

Sentence c. Technically, this is correct grammar, but very hard to read. When we read, "They took John to..." we expect the next word to be *a location*. Instead, we get a verb. Not only that, but the verb sounds very much like "prison", which is a location.

So we read it again, and since it's followed by a verb, the next thing it could mean is, "They took John (in order) to...", but that leaves "imprison" without an object, but it's a transitive verb. You have to imprison *someone*. So that doesn't work either.

On a third reading, a native speaker *might* realize that "take" can also mean "select". Now it's finally a proper sentence, with the meaning, "They selected John for imprisonment." Sentence c. has the same structure as, "*I took a sandwich to eat on the bus.*" It's unnatural to use this structure with "imprison".

Sentence d. is correct and natural.